# Transistor / mosfet for PWM dimming of 30W RGB LED

Tags: led, transistors, mosfet, pwm, controller

I am building a led mood light with a high power RGB LED (30W) using 3 constant power supplies for each color.

These are the items I had in mind (but open to suggestions):

[30W Integrated RGB LED Light Bulb (10 Series and 3 in Parallel)](http://dx.com/p/30w-integrated-rgb-led-light-bulb-10-series-and-3-in-parallel-158387)
[JR-30W 30W Waterproof LED Power Driver (AC 85~265V)](http://dx.com/p/jr-30w-30w-waterproof-led-power-driver-ac-85-265v-156230)

Each color will be controlled with PWM by arduino. So far so good, the problem is that the bc337 transistors I have can only go up to 800ma so I need something significantly beefier. What is my best and simplest option here? I'm not very knowledgeable in electronics so simplest solution would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the specifications of the device you linked are grossly inadequate.... but given you have 10 LEDs in series, I expect you'll operate at something like 40VDC...

Arduino analogWrite function generates PWM at about 490Hz.

I would suggest setting up a high side switch with a P-channel MOSFET (e.g. IRF9Z24) conrolled by an NPN BJT (e.g. 2N3904). Say 100ohm resistor into the base of the BJT and a 4.7kohm pullup on the gate of the MOSFET. Connect LED between MOSFET drain and GND. Connect PWM input to the aforementioned 100 ohm resistor.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Will keep it open for a bit until I know I have it all figured out :)

Comment: actually 32~36v for LED's which is what he spec'd as his chosen power supply 24~36V except these are 3 strings.  YOu can choose $0.20 HEXFETs in SMT with 150 mOhm Ron or use the Thru-hole parts, without heatsink.  Use a series 4K7 between collector and Gate 4K7 to reduce Vgs 50%  , no zener needed.    You might want to consider the 50W version, but your bigger problem is a good LED heatsink...& fixture  A CPU heatsink can be retrofit with a low speed fan.   I recently posted a PWM circuit with 3 pots, but you can use Music to drive each color using Bass, mid, treble filters and rectifiers.

Answer (score 0):

This should perhaps be a comment, but I couldn't see how to do that.

Most FETs like the IRF9Z24 have a 20V maximum gate to source.  So,
you should add a 10V zener across R2, and another 4.7K resistor in
series between T1 collector and Q1 gate R2 node.

Comment: Unless I am reading the wrong thing the only voltage value I see is 60V. Take a look at the spec and let me know if it's 60v or 20v: Spec: http://www.vishay.com/docs/91090/91090.pdf

Comment: Look in the absolute maximum table on sheet 1, second row ... Gate-Source Voltage ... +/-20V limit.  It appears that the circuit as drawn would put 40V gate to source when T1 is on.